# ViewPager fragments created but not beeing displayed on Android <= Jellybean

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, xamarin.android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_container_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_container_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/some_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have inserted a fragment in **main_container_1** which has a layout with a **viewPager** created programmatically. Here is the OnCreateView of the **first** fragment

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var frameLayout = new FrameLayout(Activity)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent)
        };

        _viewPager = new ViewPager(Activity);

        //It is required that view pager have an ID othe than -1
        _viewPager.Id = 0x00000001;

        _viewPager.PageSelected += _viewPager_PageSelected;

        _progressBar = new ProgressBar(Activity)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, GravityFlags.Center)
        };

        frameLayout.AddView(_viewPager);
        frameLayout.AddView(_progressBar);

        return frameLayout;
    }
```

Of course, later on, I bind my data via an FragmentStatePagerAdapter to the viewPager.

**Result**: The child fragments contained in the first fragment display properly

I do the same operation for a **second** fragment in **main_container_2** of a different type which has the following onCreateView

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        _myCustomContainer = (MyCustomLayout)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyCustomLayout, container, false);

        _viewPager = new ViewPager(Activity);
        _myCustomContainer.AddView(_viewPager);
        //It is required that view pager have an ID othe than -1
        _viewPager.Id = 0x00000001;

        return _myCustomContainer;
    }
```

I use the same type of FragmentStatePagerAdapter as for the first viewPager of the **first** fragment.

**Result**: On Android version lower or equal to Jellybean (API 16), the child fragments of the **second** fragment are **created** but not displayed.

Here is the GetItem method of my implementation of the FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        if (!ActiveFragments.ContainsKey(position))
        {
            var fragment = PagedCustomFragment.NewPagedCustomFragment(position);

            ActiveFragments[position] = fragment;
        }

        return ActiveFragments[position];
    }
```

**Question**: Why are the child fragments of the second fragments not shown?

Comment: Please tag this for whatever programming environment that you are using, as this clearly is not Java. With respect to your problem, nested fragments (e.g., a fragment holding a `ViewPager` holding fragments) is not supported using native fragments prior to API Level 17. You would have to use the fragments backport from the Android Support package.

Comment: I have tagged it with monodroid since it was coded using C#. Also, I understand that I should expect unsupported feature to simply not be usable but as I mention, the first fragment which contain view pager works perfectly and has been working for almost a year now. Is it unreasonnable on my part to expect that the second fragment works as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your ViewPagers seem to belong to the same parent and also have the same ID, which might be the root cause of your issue. Have you tried to use a different ID for each ViewPager?

Comment: IT WORKS! Changing the ID of the second view pager fixed my issue! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!